# Updating Module Via Composer will NOT Update Module?

Tags: magento2.3, module, composer, compose-update

When Updating Module Via Composer it will not Update Module on my localhostx?

When I put this line. I get this error on my local host.

`composer require "route/route-m2"`

`Could not find a matching version of package route/route-m2. Check the pack age spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability`

If I try `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=6G composer update 'route/route-m2'` I get

`Nothing to install or update`

Am I putting in the wrong syntax?? I am so confused.

Comment: Where is package route/route-m2 hosted?

Comment: On Production site it can be updated with Composer update. However, on local host it will not update. And composer install did not work.  What do you mean where is it hosted? Here is the documentation on the route module here. https://magento.routeapp.io/magento2/index.html#installation

Comment: @amitshree. Any idea why I can not update this module on my local host?

Comment: Should I delete var/composer_home folder and try?

Comment: Have you tried running command without quotes? `composer require route/route-m2`. Also, if it is local environment, you can delete generated/* and var/* folder and try again.

Comment: @amitshree yes, I have tried everything. I just decided to go on my production site and FTP the files from the vendor/route folder and put them in my local vendor/route folder. Haha probably not the best way to do that or the proper way. However, no matter how many times i tried updating the module with composer it would not update.  And I could update several other modules with Composer so strange.

Comment: Yes, looks strange. Not sure if you have tried clearing composer cache using `composer clear-cache`. Also try deleting composer.lock and run the command again and check.

Comment: I tried that as well. Still no luck. Its strange now because my compser.lock says I still have module 1.1.5 but My folder and module in Magento says im on 1.1.7.

Comment: @amitshree very strange when I do compose update after deleting composer.lock. it will keep my composer.lock at 1.1.5 but my module stays at 1.1.7 and its composer.json says 1.1.7 but bc I manually put folders there.

Comment: Yes, you have already added files manually. To test this you can place older version and try to update after deleting composer.lock and clearing composer cache.

Comment: @amitshree Can I just delete vendor/route/route-m2 folder delete the module? Then run Composer Update or require and that should require the new route module? Thats what I am thinking I will try when I have some time. Thank you for all your help!!!!

Comment: So I will probably just delete module and and re download it through Composer.

Comment: Yes, delete it and re-download it.

Comment: Its working! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here are the things which can be tried in this scenario:

- Clear composer cache and retry using `composer clear-cache`.
- Try composer require without quotes `composer require route/route-m2`.
- Delete `composer.lock` , delete already installed module from vendor folder, clear cache using `composer clear-cache` and re-install module via composer using `composer require route/route-m2`.